# Unable to update/recreate ES index: mapper_parsing_exception (ES7)

Tags: elasticsearch

I created an index called 't_documents' with the following mapping:

```
{
   "settings": {
        "index": {
             "mapping.total_fields.limit": "2000",
              "number_of_shards": 5,
              "number_of_replicas": 1,
        }
   },
   "mappings": {
          "properties": {
                "id": { "type": "keyword"},
                "title": { "type": "keyword"},
                "content": { "type": "keyword"},
                "file_location": { "type": "keyword"} 
          }
  }
}
```

I deleted the index and recreated with the following mapping:
(Showing only the "mappings" part)

```
 "mappings": {
          "properties": {
                "id": { "type": "keyword"},
                "title": { "type": "keyword"},
                "content": { "type": "keyword"},
                "file_location": { "type": "keyword"} ,
                "timestamp": { "type": "keyword"} 
          }
  }
```

I encountered the following error message:

```
root_cause: [{
   type: mapper_parsing_exception
    reason: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters: [file_location: {type=keyword}] [content: {type=keyword}] [title: {type=keyword}] [id: {type=keyword}]
}]
```

This happens when I tried to PUT it into a totally new index too.

I could not find any useful information on ElasticSearch website as well.

## I am using ES7

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this.

Create a blank mapping for your index

```
PUT /t_documents
{}
```

Then, for each field in your index, do this

```
PUT /t_documents/_mapping/{field name}
{ "properties": {
     "{field name}": {
            "type": ...
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is quite a cumbersome approach, It should have worked earlier if you had deleted the index properly .. can you please share your postman collection with all of your rquests so that I can help you